# Session timeout security concerns

Tags: security, session, timeout, e-commerce

I am creating an e-commerce site. Long session timeouts would be really convenient for customers. I think the shortest acceptable timeout would be a week.

I read about the security risks of long session timeouts. However, it allows me to return to websites after a month and I'm still logged in. Sites like `stackoverflow.com`, `gog.com`, and `g2a.com` all use long session timeouts. What is the general rule about this?

Some sites use short session timeouts but automatically check a "Remember me" checkbox or use a token in a cookie with the same result. Is there any difference?

Comment: Amazon, for example, allows you to stay logged in perpetually and browse the site, but requires you to re-authenticate after a few hours if you perform some sensitive action like finalizing a purchase or viewing account details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you by default allow long session timeouts, then the risk is on shared computers - future user accesses the session of the current user.  If you try to blame the user for not logging out, then you will find your user base dwindle and you will have to deal with a lot of end user complaints.

Best practice is to have short timeout by default, but allow an option 'remember me on this device' so that people can opt to long sessions if they are in a trusted environment.  The golden rule is "**secure by default**".

Comment: It is very is to say that the golden rule is "secure by default", but on the other hand there are the customers who are lazy and expect convenience. The convenience is a key factor for them. Without this convenience they can easily choose another e-commerce site.

Comment: @igoemon, okay do it the other wAy and then let me know how it goes :-)

Comment: I will test it. What could be the worst case scenario? Somebody else order something with postpaid (because a fake customer doesn't know the payment details). In this case the customer simple send back the order. If it happens too often we can switch back to a shorter session timeout.

Comment: @igoemon I don't know enough about your application to say worst case scenario, but typically someone who gets access to another person's session can also access their private details (name, address, etc) and potentially other sensitive information.  Next time you go to a shared computer, for example at the airport, look through the browser history and go to sites that are in there and see what you can access.  You will be surprised.  Generally, the goal in usable security is "secure by default" but make it easy for users to do what they want.  My answer above took that approach.

Comment: I think there is no proper answer without the details of the given application so I have to accept your answer. Every steps which are loosing on the security have to be considered wisely depends on the given application.